# Arrest for civil violation in the US?

Tags: united-states, us-federal-government

Immigration officers in the US can arrest people who have violated immigration law, even if the violation is not criminal ([8 USC 1357(a)(2)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1357#a_2), [8 CFR 287.5(c)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/287.5#c_1)).  Are there other examples of civil violations in the US that can lead to arrest of the violator?

Comment: "Detain" is not the same as "arrest"; which do you mean? I read one citation to mean that an officer can detain a suspect until he can be lawfully arrested.

Comment: @TimLymington where do you see the word "detain"?  I see only "arrest."

Comment: Are you only interested in civil crimes at the federal level?

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't think there's such a thing as a "civil crime," since civil violations are by definition distinct from criminal violations. I am principally interested in federal civil violations, yes, but not exclusively.  If you have something interesting to say about the situation in any state, please say it.

Comment: [Civil Arrest Warrants for Texas Democratic Legislators](https://www.statesman.com/story/news/politics/state/2021/08/10/texas-house-speaker-signs-arrest-warrants-absent-democrats/5563807001/)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson you seem to have posted an answer in the space for comments.  Though I'm not sure that a legislator failing to attend a session is a "violation" in the same sense that overstaying a visa is.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

Contempt of court is an example, I’m sure there are others.